# изменить переменную среды path из bat файла

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть SFX-архив, он используется как установщик для маленькой программы. Архив распаковывается, и после распаковки выполняется bat-файл с таким содержанием:

```
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\example\
```

Он должен добавить путь к распаковавшемуся архиву в Path. Но этого не происходит. Пробовал запускать от имени администратора - не помогло.

Comment: Не оно https://superuser.com/a/1070878/505198?

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.